# Odds of a specific dice distribution occuring when playing Catan (2d6)

Tags: probability, dice

So this is messing with me, because I have no idea how I would even go about starting calculating this.

I have played a game of Catan. For those that don't know, it's a board game that involves rolling two D6 per turn. So there are 12 possible outcomes for each roll, but each number has a different probability of occuring.

During a game, we had the following dice rolls occur over a 69 turn game:

- **2:** 5
- **3:** 6
- **4:** 5
- **5:** 11
- **6:** 7
- **7:** 9
- **8:** 8
- **9:** 9
- **10:** 0
- **11:** 8
- **12:** 3

This lead to the conversation about what are the odds of no 10s occuring (easy to calculate, it's `(33/36)^69 = 1 in ~400`). This further then lead to a conversation about how rare any given combination of rolls is. I just wanted to calculate some lower and upper bounds, but I honestly had no idea how to:

A: Deal with the fact that the odds of each number are different
B: Deal with the fact that [A, A, B] = [B, A, A]

**So my question is how do I go about calculating the probability of any given combination of numbers?** Just getting me started looking in the right place would help a lot.

---

An upper bound is easy. The worse case is rolling all 2s (or 12s), for which the odds are `1/36^69 = 4e-108`, but beyond that I'm stuck.

A "simpler" solution that I would also be happy with, would be the odds of the "perfect" distribution occuring during a 72 move game. So two 2s, four 3s, six 4s, etc. Every number perfectly matching its frequency. This also represents a lower bound for the probability of any given dice combination (in a 72 move game)

No idea how hard or complicated this is. But I thought I would ask. If there's somewhere better to ask, just redirect me and I'll ask there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is required to compute the probabilities which are:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
i&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
p_i\times\frac1{36}&1&2&3&4&5&6&5&4&3&2&1
\end{array}
$$

The probability of a specific outcome $n_2$ of '2', $n_3$ of '3' and so on after $n$ rounds ($\sum_i n_i=n$) can be computed as:
$$
n!\prod_{i=2}^{12}\frac{p_i^{n_i}}{n_i!}.
$$

Comment: To be clear. I was able to work this out (and said as much in my answer). I'm trying to work out how to solve the more generic question, of how common any given dice distribution is. As a simple example, given a D6 that you roll 18 times. What percentage of the time does this result in 3 of every number?

Comment: @Pluckerpluck I have edited the answer. Sorry that I have not read your question carefully enough. Is it now what you were looking for?

Comment: It is! Such a simple equation as well, and fairly intuative with how it works. Tested it out on some simple scenarios. e.g. d6 with [1, 1, 1] -> 0.46% and [1, 2, 3] -> 2.78%. Awesome thank!

Comment: You are welcome!